# Only last StackPane is rendered on the screen (JavaFX)

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to display a chessboard with multiple queens on the board but it only displays one of them. I hava a 2D `int` array that I walk through and and only want to render a queen on the occupied squares.

```
public class Test5 extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Label Queen = new Label("Q");
        Queen.setTextFill(Color.web("#0076a3"));
        Queen.setFont(new Font(30));

        GridPane root = new GridPane();
        Random random = new Random();
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 1000, 1000));

        int[][] b = {
            {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1},
            {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1},
            {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1},
            {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1},
            {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1},
            {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1},
            {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1},
            {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1},
            {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1},
            {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1},
        };



        final Animation animation = new Transition() {
            {
                setCycleDuration(Duration.INDEFINITE);
            }

            protected void interpolate(double frac) {


                //Iterate over loop and whenever a position is occupied add Queen to that particular StackPane
                for(int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
                    for(int j = 0; j < b.length; j++) {
                        if(b[i][j] == 1) {
                            StackPane place = (StackPane)root.getChildren().get(i * 10 + j);
                            place.getChildren().add(Queen);
                        }
                    }
                }

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                }
                catch(Exception e) {

                };
            }

        }; 


        for (int row = 0; row < 10; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < 10; col ++) {
                StackPane square = new StackPane();
                String color ;
                if ((row + col) % 2 == 0) {
                    color = "white";
                } else {
                    color = "black";
                }


                square.setStyle("-fx-background-color: "+color+";"); 



                root.add(square, col, row);



            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            root.getColumnConstraints().add(new ColumnConstraints(10, Control.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, Priority.ALWAYS, HPos.CENTER, true));
            root.getRowConstraints().add(new RowConstraints(10, Control.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, Priority.ALWAYS, VPos.CENTER, true));
        }




        animation.play();

        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test5.launch();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't sleep on the FX Application thread; you prevent it from rendering. Additionally, you can't add the same node multiple times to the scene graph. It's not really clear what you're trying to do here, but you've misunderstood how the animation API works.

Comment: Yes, I create a new node and now it works. It's very sluggish when I resize which may be due to ```Thread.sleep()```. Is there alternative to wait before rendering another configuration. Thank you for your input.

Comment: Use a [`Timeline`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/animation/Timeline.html).